# How write a regex these patterns : 'AA AA', 'AB AB' not 'AA AB' and 'AA AC'

Tags: regex

How write a regex that produces the following matches:

```
A A [passed]
B B [failed]
AA AA [passed]
a a [failed]
A [failed]
AA AB [failed]
AB AB [passed]
AC AC [passed]
ABB ABB [passed]
ACC ACC [failed]
ABC ABC [passed]
ABBC ABBC [passed]
AABBC AABBC [passed]
BC BC [failed]
AD AD [failed]
AABBC AABB [failed]
AAA [failed]
123 123 [failed]
ABCZ ABCZ [failed]
```

Regex must score exactly 8 right matches and 0 wrong matches. An example regex is [A-Z]+.

Comment: Any attempts? Also, what are the rules for passing and failing? What language/environment are you using the regex in?

Comment: i tried tried this regex pattern ^A(A*B*C{0,1}) A(A*B*C{0,1}), but i can't to except "AA AB" and "AABBC AABB".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the pattern:

```
^(A+B*C?) \1$
```

Begins with `A`, with any number of `B` and one optional `C`. Then capture that first part, match a space, then try to match what was initially matched, ensuring that there's nothing more than that.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/zE4cW8)

The demo above uses `^(A+B*C?) \1\b` which works with the `[passed]` or `[failed]` tags at the end. If you want to use `$` instead, you will have to remove all the `[passed]` and `[failed]` tags.

There's no explicit rule mentioned, so the regex might need adjustments if there happen to be any.

Comment: thanks Jerry, its worked,, B)